# update my xampp installation from 5.3 to 5.5 or 5.6 - on power pc mac 10.5

Tags: php, macos, xampp, codeigniter-3

I have php 5.6.38 downloaded but I can't get my xampp installed to see the new version of php, is there a way to get a php 5638.so file that xampp will see? Or do i need to go about this completely differently?  I'm trying to run a codeigniter project that relies on having php 5.4, the installed xampp version is 5.31.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If I get it correctly, you have installed XAMPP (including PHP 5.3) on your PC. And now you wan't to update PHP to the version 5.5 / 5.5? Right? Wouldn't it be easier to update the complete XAMPP installation?

Comment: thanks Benjamin, but this is for a power pc MAC and I can't install a later version of xampp because my system is end of life. thanks

Comment: OK. I didn't think about it. Also I don't have XAMPP on my Mac, so I'm not sure about the path structure. From where do you have downloaded the PHP version 5.6.38? Do you know in which folder your old PHP version 5.31 is installed?

Comment: 5.31 is in applications>xampp>xamppfiles>lib>php>php-5.3.1, 5.6.38 is in the same php folder but there's no way to change the httpd.conf file to see that folder because in the httpd.conf file it has a command to load module php5_module  modules/libphp5.so and i have no way to generate a new version of the .so file

Comment: I have to pass at the moment, because I can't test it. Sorry.